# Why my angular function is called more than length of array?

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I am trying to figure out why my angular app get stuck to a infinite loop and that investigation lead me this simple issue. I have a array of id's and array of models. I am trying to show all models which are present in id's list. See console logging in https://jsfiddle.net/SNummelin/hyow2fL6/.

#### Console logs:

```
(index):57 getModel called with 111
(index):57 getModel called with 111
(index):57 getModel called with 222
(index):57 getModel called with 222
(index):57 getModel called with 111
(index):57 getModel called with 222
```

#### html:

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
  {{modelIds.length}} / {{models.length}}
  <div ng-repeat="id in modelIds">
    <div ng-bind-html=getModel(id)></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### angular:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.modelIds = ['111', '222'];
    $scope.models = [{
      id: '111',
      name: "Eka"
    }, {
      id: '222',
      name: "Eka"
    }];

  $scope.getModel = function(id) {
    console.log("getModel called with " + id);
    var ret = "";
    $scope.models.forEach(function(model) {
      if (model.id === id)
        ret += model.name;
      }, this);
    return $sce.trustAsHtml("<div>" + ret + "</div>");
  }
});
```

Comment: Angular will call that function at least twice per digest cycle for each element in array. Your approach is very inefficient. Use a filter instead or even better do your own filtering before passing data to view

Comment: I agree, you should build your own filter first to use with ngRepeat.. something like filterIds : modelIds

Comment: check this out https://toddmotto.com/everything-about-custom-filters-in-angular-js/

Comment: This is by means no production code, just trying to get in deep of angular. Filtering of data is of course needed to get code more efficient. @charlietf why angular calls functions more than once per digest cycle? Is there a way to control that?

Comment: Because digests are run a minimum of 2 times per cycle to make sure scope is stable. Any changes to scope within this cycle will cause additional digests